# how can i print all the passes in the bubble sort

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting

Is there any way I can show all the passes that the bubble sort make just like in the picture below?

this is the code for the bubble sort which i have ;

```
def bubble_sort(list_a):
    exchanges = True
    i = len(list_a)-1
while i > 0 and exchanges:
    exchanges = False
    for j in range(i):
        if list_a[j]>list_a[j+1]:
            exchanges = True
            list_a[j], list_a[j+1] = list_a[j+1], list_a[j]
    i -= 1


list_a = [70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10]
bubble_sort(list_a)
print(list_a)
```

[Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBTfR.png)

Comment: You would start by writing a python program that does bubble sort.

Comment: I do have a program for bubble sort but it just gives the arranged list, it does not show the passes.

Comment: Then please try to modify this program and include it in your question here.

Comment: 1. Set up your array. 2. Do a single pass of bubble sort. 3. Print the current state of the array. 4. If the array is not yet sorted go back to #2.

Comment: I added the code in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print the array at every swap using the following code:

```
def bubble_sort(list_a):
    exchanges = True
    i = len(list_a)-1
    while i > 0 and exchanges:
        exchanges = False
        for j in range(i):
            if list_a[j]>list_a[j+1]:
                exchanges = True
                list_a[j], list_a[j+1] = list_a[j+1], list_a[j]
                #You print the contents of the array after every swap
                print("After pass " + str(i) + ", inner loop "+ str(j) + ": " + str(list_a)) 
        i -= 1

#The following code is only to test the Bubble Sort, so nothing has to be changed here    
list_a = [70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10]
bubble_sort(list_a)
print(list_a)
```

Or you can print the array at every pass using the following code:

```
def bubble_sort(list_a):
    exchanges = True
    i = len(list_a)-1
    while i > 0 and exchanges:
        exchanges = False
        for j in range(i):
            if list_a[j]>list_a[j+1]:
                exchanges = True
                list_a[j], list_a[j+1] = list_a[j+1], list_a[j]
        #You print the contents of the array after every pass
        print("After pass " + str(i) + ": " + str(list_a)) 
        i -= 1

#The following code is only to test the Bubble Sort, so nothing has to be changed here    
list_a = [70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10]
bubble_sort(list_a)
print(list_a)
```

As you can see, the difference is in where you add the print statement.

You can also take a look at a cleaner implementation of Bubble Sort, which could make the whole algorithm easier to understand:

```
def bubbleSort(arr): 
    n = len(arr) 
    for i in range(n-1): 
        for j in range(0, n-i-1): 
            if arr[j] > arr[j+1] : 
                arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j]
                #I have included this line so it prints the array at every swap
                print("After pass " + str(i) + ", inner loop "+ str(j) + ": " + str(arr))
```

Comment: the code works wonders! thank you very much although I have one more question, how do I show the number of each pass and swap for example the output should look like "After pass 1, inner loop 1: [60, 70, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10] i guess first pass will have 6 loops and second will have 5 and so on but how can I show that? do I have to type print again and again?

Comment: I get this error : || TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str || And I get this in two lines, first one where you print "print("After pass " + i + ", inner loop "+ j + ": " + arr)" and second time when i call the function

Comment: I suppose you're new to Python. You don't get it twice but only when you call the function, which receives the error from the bubble sort function. This is called a stack trace. Anyway, I'm updating the answer to reflect that issue. Sorry about that, I haven't touched Python in a while and I sometimes forget its shortcomings.

Comment: actually yes for matter of fact i am new to python and to coding as well! And uhm I put the variables as str() so it worked. now one last thing,  the output i am getting starts off by " After pass 6, inner loop 0:" can I somehow start from pass 1 till pass 6? like the opposite way and also for the inner loop how can i start it from 1 instead of 0. sorry about so any issues I appreciate you assistance.

Comment: Instead of "str(i)" write "str(i+1)". It is not advisable to actually make the loop start from 1 as arrays start from 0. My tip would be to get used to arrays and loops starting from 0 as Python isn't the only language you'll see this in, not by far, and eventually, you'll start to appreciate that (just believe me on this).